# Analogies between Drinfeld modules and Elliptic curves

Tags: soft-question, elliptic-curves, class-field-theory

I have just started reading Drinfeld Modules and them very hard to visualize them, but the terminology sounds much similar to that of Elliptic curve to be precise

1. Hasse invariant - j invariant
2. Complex multiplication
3. Super Singularity

Also any help for visualizing rank-2 Drinfeld modules (of the form)
$$\phi : \mathbb{F}_p[x] \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}_p(x)<\tau> $$  would be of great help !